# Meaning of "Propaganda"

Tags: meaning

I am confused about the meaning of the word propaganda
I've read on the internet that propaganda means deliberate spreading of rumors to help or harm a person, idea, etc..
So it is something that is "bad" but at the same time I've seen many people using the word propaganda in a "good" way. For example Joseph Goebbels was a minister of propaganda.

Comment: What do reasonable dictionaries say? The ones I've checked in almost all have variations on the caveat '**especially** of a biased or misleading nature'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't have one, I am not native speaker either.

Comment: You're on the Internet. Look up "propaganda" +  "meaning". Collins, AHDEL, M-W, ODO, CDO ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Collins' says that it means  "information, often inaccurate", why would any political organization would want to call it propaganda instead of using another word that is always positive? Did the meaning change in the more recent times?

Comment: Your Goebbels example would hardly be considered as carrying a positive appraisal (amongst native English speakers). It's usually opponents or cynics who label the dissemination of information as 'propaganda'. And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_propaganda) puts the circle-argument: 'Though governments routinely engage in propaganda, ministries with the word "propaganda" in their name have become progressively more rare since the end of World War II, as a result of which the term took on its present negative connotation.'

Comment: @Hugh No; it's an English word we're discussing here. And as the Wikipedia article states, the negative tone has become very marked since the events of WWII.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I rather suspect that ministries were renamed because of a shift in the word's connotation rather than the other way around.

Comment: @phoog As I stated. But as Wikipedia implies, it's almost certainly a vicious circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Propaganda***, according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=p&p=67&allowed_in_frame=0:), was originally an eminently respectable word, originated by the Catholic church, and expanded to a still respectable political sense around the time of WW1.

> 1718, "committee of cardinals in charge of Catholic missionary work,"
>   short for Congregatio de Propaganda Fide "congregation for propagating
>   the faith," a committee of cardinals established 1622 by Gregory XV to
>   supervise foreign missions. The word is properly the ablative fem.
>   gerundive of Latin propagare (see propagation). Hence, "any movement
>   to propagate some practice or ideology" (1790). Modern political sense
>   dates from World War I, not originally pejorative. Meaning "material
>   or information propagated to advance a cause, etc." is from 1929.

[Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda) historical discussion differs a bit from that of Etymonline:

> From the 1790s, the term began being used also for propaganda in
>   secular activities. The term began taking a pejorative connotation
>   in the mid-19th century, when it was used in the political sphere.....
>
> Also in the early 20th century the term propaganda was used by the
>   founders of the nascent public relations industry to refer to their
>   activities. This usage died out around the time of World War II, as
>   the industry started to avoid the word, given the pejorative
>   connotation it had acquired

The use of propaganda by the Nazis in WWII was the death knell of the word as describing a respectable activity.